# Angular js tab refresh issue

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using same component for *2 tabs* and based on the flag I am loading data but when I refresh the tab always it taking first tab url and it is loading first tab data please suggest any solution.

here is my code

```
 this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
  console.log(this.currentUrl);
  if(this.currentUrl == "/defaultTab"){
```

//by default first tab will load

```
      this.currentUrl+="/firstTab";
      this.router.navigate([this.currentUrl]);      
  }

  else {
    var isSecondTab= this.router.url.split("/").filter(function(val) {
       return val === "secondTab";
      }).length;
       if(isSecondTab == 1){      
         let newUrl = "/defaultTab";
         newUrl+="/secondTab";
          this.router.navigate([newUrl]);  
       }

    var isFirstTab = this.router.url.split("/").filter(function(val) {
       return val === "firstTab";
      }).length;
       if(isFirstTab == 1){
          let newUrl = "/defaultTab";
         newUrl+="/firstTab";
          this.router.navigate([newUrl]);  
       }


  }
```

Comment: Please share your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

By Default only you put the condition for the url's ,than you restrict the first url execution.i thought you put the condition for second url.

Comment: No I am not giving any condition this.router.url is taking first url  this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
      console.log(this.currentUrl);

Comment: what value in console for this.currenturl

Comment: /defaultTab/firstTab    even afetr refresh also(when I am in 2nd tab) it is showing currentUrl is /defaultTab/firstTab

Comment: hi,by default you condition is false thatswhy it go to else condition and executes first url block.ince you click on the second tab please invoke one more method here